# How much Bandwidth does an Express Card slot on a Laptop put out?

Tags: compatibility, graphics, pci-express

I want to buy a [Dell M6800 Laptop](http://configure.us.dell.com/dellstore/config.aspx?oc=s) workstation.

1. Can someone tell me how much bandwidth does 54 mm Express Card slot put out ?
2. Also how many lanes of PCIe that slot has ? ( x1, x4, x8, x16 )
3. How do I find out above info ?
4. Can I connect this [PCIe Expansion box](http://www.netstor.com.tw/_03/03_02.php?OTc=) in it's Express Card slot ?
5. If yes, how much bandwidth each slot of that box would receive ?

Answer (score 0):

(1) From [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ExpressCard):

> The ExpressCard has a maximum throughput of 2.5 Gbit/s through PCI
>   Express and 480 Mbit/s through USB 2.0 dedicated for each slot, while
>   all CardBus and PCI devices connected to a computer usually share a
>   total 1.06 Gbit/s bandwidth.

(2) From [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ExpressCard), again:

> direct connection to the system bus over a PCI Express ×1 lane

(3) Googling or asking here

(4) Yes, if you buy "NA211A(NB) for Laptop" from your link.

(5) You must ask the manufacturer of this box, but I don't think they have control over it. It is "first come - first serve" from 2.5 Gbit/s total.